# PDO: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dojo

Here are texts in order:

login -> select database -> select from a given list of cards -> mysql-process to produce a list of tests -> select a test -> mysql-process to produce a batch number based on selected card and test.

A script "mysql-process to produce a list of tests" is working that I am able to select one of the tests.

Then the error pops up `exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'`.

Why is that the  error stated that No Database selected though database is already selected.

There are 2 php files: `gathertests2.php` (working) and `gatherbatches.php` (not working).

**main.php(excerpt1)**

```
on(selPCBA, 'change', function(value)
{console.debug('value = '+value);
var selectedPCBA = this.get('displayedValue');
console.debug('Contents of "selected" variable ='+selectedPCBA);
var selTest = registry.byId('ID_selTest');
    if (selectedPCBA.indexOf("class='inUse'")!==-1)
         {request.post('gathertests2.php',
    {data:{testDB : value},
    handleAs: "json"}).then
    (
         function(response)
        {var memoStore1 = new Memory({data:response});
                selTest.set('store', memoStore1);
            selTest.set('value','');
        },
     function(error)
            {alert("Test's Error:"+error);
    });
         selTest.startup();
    }
   else
     {console.debug('Error:- Attempting to select the unavailable card');
      alert('Please select the only highlighted card');
}
});
```

**gathertests2.php**

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/firephp_include.php');
$firephp->setEnabled(TRUE);
$firephp->info('Start debugging in gathertest2.php');
require_once '../scripts/login.php';
    $db = $_POST['testDB'];
$stmt_use = $dbh->prepare("use $db");//ok
$firephp->fb($stmt_use);

    try //PDO Driver is used in PHP for working with MySQL!!!!
    {
        $stmt_use  -> execute();//ok
        $firephp->log("Successfully executed!");
    }

    catch (PDOException $err) //PDOException is declared in login.php
    {
        $alertmsg = $err->getMessage();
        include 'alertmessage.php';
        $firephp->error("Unsuccessfully executing: $err");
    }
    $stmt_call1 = $dbh->prepare('call listmfg_codes()');
$firephp->fb($stmt_call1);

    try //PDO Driver is used in PHP for working with MySQL!!!!
    {
        $stmt_call1->execute();
        $firephp->log("Successfully executed!");
    }

    catch (PDOException $err) //PDOException is declared in login.php
    {
        $alertmsg = $err->getMessage();
        include 'alertmessage.php';
        $firephp->error("Unsuccessfully executing: $err");
    }

$result = $stmt_call1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //ok
$output = json_encode($result); 
echo $output;
$firephp -> fb($result);
$firephp -> info("End");
```

where `call listmfg_codes()` is

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testdata2060_03`.`listmfg_codes` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `listmfg_codes`()
BEGIN
select distinct(mfg_code) from test order by mfg_code asc;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**main.php(excerpt2)**

```
on(selTest, 'change', function(value)
    {var selectedTest = this.get('displayedValue');
 var selBatch = registry.byId('ID_selBatch');
 request.post('gatherbatches.php',
    {data:{testCard : value},
     handleAs: "json"}).then
(
    function(response)
    {var memoStore2 = new Memory({data:response});
     selBatch.set('store', memoStore2);
    selBatch.set('value','');
    },
   function(error)
       {alert("Batch's Error:"+error);
    }
);
       selBatch.startup();
 });
```

**gatherbatches.php**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/firephp_include.php');
$firephp->setEnabled(TRUE);
$firephp->warn('Start debugging in gatherbatches.php');
require_once '../scripts/login.php';
    $card = $_POST['testCard'];//must add '' in "" bracket for call command to work
$stmt_call2 = $dbh->prepare("call listbatch('$card')");
$firephp->fb($stmt_call2);
try //PDO Driver is used in PHP for working with MySQL!!!!
    {
        $stmt_call2->execute();
        $firephp->log("Successfully executed!");
    }

catch (PDOException $err) //PDOException is declared in login.php
    {
        $alertmsg = $err->getMessage();
        include 'alertmessage.php';
        $firephp->error("Unsuccessfully executing: $err");  
        }

$result = $stmt_call2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //ok
    $output = json_encode($result); 
echo $output;
$firephp -> fb($result);
$firephp -> warn("End");
```

where `call listbatch()` is

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testdata2060_03`.`listbatch` $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `listbatch`(mfgnum VARCHAR(24))
 BEGIN
     SELECT batch FROM test WHERE mfg_code = mfgnum group by batch order by batch desc;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

OK It's done.
Please advise where I go wrong. Please see the attached below:

[image]

//Added login.php

```
<?php 
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;Port=3306';
   $user = 'root'; $pswd = '';
   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE));     
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
  ?>
```

Comment: where did you initialize $dbh variable .. make sure you it looks like $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');

Comment: $dbh variable is initalised in '../scripts/login.php'. see require_once command. Because of this, I am able to connect to database and gathertests2.php is working. But gatherbatches.php is not working.

Comment: @user1739825, show login.php

Comment: <?php
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; Port=3306';
 $user = 'root';
 $pswd = '';
 $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd,
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 
?>

Comment: Looking at your phpfire log, looks like you select the database on the gathertests2.php but you don't in your gatherbatches.php. You have the "$stmt_use = $dbh->prepare("use $db")" sentence in gathertest2.php and you don't select the database anywhere in gatherbatches.php

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all that load of codes, but I have a feeling that it's your idea of how PHP works is wrong.

Most likely you imagine a client-server application like a desktop one - solid and standalone. This is wrong. All these AJAX calls being made to *separate and clean* PHP instances, knowing nothing of previous executions. Thus, whatever databases you selected in previous calls won't help you in the current one - **you have to init all the resources again.**

There is also one **extremely strange thing**: you are **passing a db name from client side**! I'd call it weird behavior, both from architectural and security points of view. Moreover, there is not a single reason to have multiple databases for such a localized case like several tests.

So, make it usual and proper way:

- use **one** database
- select it once, in login.php
- probably rearrange your tests, using **one** table to hold **all** the similar data

and you will have not a single trouble ever.

Comment: Turns out that "$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);" is a culpirt. Nowever, there is no record updated even though "ATTR_ERRMODE" is removed as there is no error. The gathertests2.php works and gatherbatch is not working.

Comment: Turns out again that  "$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);" has nothing to do with it. Instead, It seems that the name of database needs to be indicated every time  before any mysql script is executed. Isn't it?